# knockout - binding multiple variables on single element

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, websocket

I've a websocket which streams array of 100 variables. I've 10 elements created after view modal created and `ko.applybindings` called.

1. I want to observe multiple variables for same element.
2. I want to add/remove observation of variables on the fly.

Currently I'm binding single variable to element. I can write my own custom handler to process multiple variables on same element.

Please help to connect dots using knockout!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood your question, you can make use of Subscriptions for the same,

Suppose you have one variable which you want to observe..

```
self.variableToObserve = ko.observableArray();

self.variableToObserve.subscribe(function(){
   //this will be triggered when values inside self.variableToObserve is changed.. 
   //you can change values of other variables here... rest logic is yours..
});
```

Comment: Maybe you meant `subscribe`, not `subscription`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.. Wrote in flow of other thoughts :P

Comment: Where can I apply custom bindingHandler in this code flow?

Comment: Some code snippet would be helpful, so that we can help you writing custom binding handler :-) Since you want to observe multiple variables for same element I suggested subscribe..

Comment: For instance, KO.bindHandler.appendString ={update: function(e, v, AB, VM, ctx){$(e).append(KO.unwrap(v()));}}.